# Love2D NewImageFont won't render

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm working on a game and have created a simple numeric "font" for displaying the number of days.

Love2D's `newImageFont()` function lets one use a [specifically-formatted image](https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Fonts_and_Text) to create a font for any number of glyphs.

I've created my font, loaded it in my `love.load()` function thus:

`dayFont = gr.newImageFont("/fonts/dayFont.png", "1234567")`

Here's the font image file:

[image]

And then in `love.draw()`, I am trying to use it to display one number:

```
love.graphics.reset()
love.graphics.setFont(dayFont)
love.graphics.printf("1", 260, 20, 30, "left")
```

But nothing appears.

While troubleshooting, I discovered that when I don't set the font, the number *does* appear in the location expected, so the problem seems to be the imageFont itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the 4th parameter of `love.graphics.printf()`, which sets the max width of the text. Because it was set to a max width of 30 pixels, and the glyphs themselves are 36 pixels wide, it simply doesn't render any glyphs at all.

Updating the line in love.draw() to:

`love.graphics.printf("1", 260, 20, 40, "left")`

fixes the issue.